# Memory in FPGA: buffer to store bytes "sent" by SPI Slave

Tags: fpga, spi, ram, dma, bram

I asked [before](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/569908/spi-slave-store-received-byte) what SPI slave is and how the received data could be stored...

SPI slave collect a byte a sent it to FIFO as a temp buffer and the next step is to send the bytes to a memory. I have read about single access register, FIFO, Dual port RAM and found the best option for me is FIFO or DMA transfer.

I need to set a counter to count a number of bytes I can store in FIFO

```
if I reach max value of bytes, output --> interrupt
```

Implementation of both given in Vivado IP catalog. I read FIFO can receive byte-wise and It would perfectly fit for my design, but it will be implemented without addressing. in such case, DMA fits better, but DMA isn't byte wise memory.

What is the best option? Could DMA be store data byte wise as FIFO? Is it better to use other type of memory?

Comment: DMA is not a memory.

Comment: What is this interrupt going to?

Comment: It seems like the question is misunderstanding key concepts so I may not have understood the inquiry correctly, but with that said - If you're thinking about DMA and all these high level interconnect options, why not just use a memory-mapped SPI controller and avoid the complexity of issuing your own responses? On the other hand, if you are hand-writing HDL, why not just express the buffer using hand-written logic and either distributed or block RAM depending on the number of bytes you need to buffer (which you haven't told us)?

Comment: @nanofarad Thank you for your comment. Could you give me a reference about memory-mapped SPI controller? Where can i read in details?

Comment: Why should your SPI slave care about DMA and all? It's not his job. It needs a register or a FIFO to buffer the received bytes.

Comment: @MituRaj I thought it is important to know characteristics of SPI slave/master for implementation of a buffer as RAM or FIFO.  data rate of SPI ?

Comment: @LeeLeeYa Here you go: https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_quad_spi/v3_2/pg153-axi-quad-spi.pdf - it's an SPI/dual SPI/quad SPI controller that sits on the AXI bus.

Answer (score 1):

In the designs I've seen or written a single latch has been used or a FIFO, in my opinion its easy to implement and you also don't have to worry about waiting for DMA to complete an operation (in the off chance that something ties up memory and the DMA get's overwritten or something else has to wait until it completes an operation).

If you can guarantee an the data will be read before it gets written, a single latch will work.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I thought about using latch, but it is not a clock process, its outputs can change as soon as the inputs changes. It could be dangerous to use them.

Answer (score 1):

The approach you use will depend on the SPI data rates you need vs. the latency of your host to respond to incoming or outgoing data.

If your data rate is really slow (like UART speeds) and your CPU fast, just one register could work. More realistically, expect that you'll have at least some shallow FIFOs in each direction with flags to indicate status (Remember, SPI is bidirectional. Even if you're only sending data back, you still have to receive data to determine the transfer details if you have more than one data source address.)

Vivado's own SPI implementation (documented in pg153) includes all the necessary hardware (FIFOs, interrupts, clock generation, etc), on an AXI4 or AXI4-Lite interface. See https://www.xilinx.com/support/documentation/ip_documentation/axi_quad_spi/v3_2/pg153-axi-quad-spi.pdf. Using some special trickery it can even share the same pins as the boot flash, saving pins on your device.

At the system level you can use DMA as a separate block to move the SPI data. The Vivado pg153 block uses register-mapped I/O so it works best with a 'CDMA' (central DMA) setup with your onboard CPU (be it MicroBlaze or an ARM core.)

If you plan to design your own SPI you have more options, one of which is to adopt a streaming interface using AXI-S alongside a control interface based on AXI4-Lite. This could be more convenient depending on how you ultimately intend to use the data.